# AngularJS 'it' test spanning two controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have my main controller `mainCtrl` and a controller for a popup modal `modalController` which passes checkbox values back to my main controller through a service.  I understand how to inject a service, but how do I test across controllers?

I've tried -

```
it('when an entity is chosen expect getEntityFromModal() to be called and its parameter and checked state passed to shareDataService.setModalEntity', inject(function (modalController) {
    expect(modalController.getEntityFromModal()).toBeDefined();


}));
```

where `modalController` is my secondary controller.  But this doesn't work.

Do I have to inject a second controller in a fashion such as this -

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile) {
    mainScope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('mainCtrl', {
        $scope: mainScope
    });
    ctrl2 = $controller('modalController', {
        $scope: modalScope
    });
}));
```

EDIT

Or do I simply create a second test file which solely tests my second controller?  This doesn't seem like a good option for testing my application.

Comment: There are Unittests and Integrationtests. Your case sounds like a case for integrationtesting with something like https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/ and testing each function itself with unittests. When your functions work, but your modal f.e. doesnt open because the template was not found, you wont catch that problem.

Comment: ^ This. In unit tests two controllers are tested separately, including their contacting parts. Mock everything but tested controller, that's the purpose of unit test.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the info.